# Site not showing in google search, and webmaster tools showing irrelevant keywords

Tags: google-search, keywords, google-index

In Google Webmaster Tools, for my relatively new website: `www.caterboxgroup.co.uk`, it says there are 3 keywords: *domain*, *registered* and *caterboxgroup*.

The two first ones do not exist in the pages anywhere so I don't really understand what it's happening.

Also, I have typed `caterboxgroup.co.uk` into google search and it returns any result.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

If you type the entire URL (i.e. `www.caterboxgroup.co.uk`) into Google search, it returns results showing your domain is indexed.

For keywords from Webmaster Tools, Google can consider keywords from pages that own link(s) to your website (you can check keywords on these pages).

No worries, your website is young, just focus on working on it.